Prove of disprove that the number of unfilled squares is always even.
There is an $n\times n$ square grid where $n$ is a positive integer. Fill in the grid in the following way:

Pick a random unfilled square $A$;
If possible, pick a random integer from $1$ to $n$ to fill in $A$ so that no square on the same row or column as $A$ has the same value as $A$.

Repeat this process until no more square can be filled. Notice that, because of the rule, some grid may be unfillable. Prove or disprove that the number of unfilled squares are always even.
Example for fillings:

A finished filling of a 4 by 4 grid


a finished filling with gaps of a 4 by 4 grid
.


I have only proved this problem for small value of $n$. I thought that this would be similar to the 15-block sliding problem. However, I could not find a solution.

Can you include your proof for small values of $n$? $n=3$ or even $n=4$ would be great!

For $n=5$, this is false. Here is a $5\times 5$ grid with $5$ unfilled cells:
\begin{array}{ccccc}
    4 & \cdot & 5 & 3 & 2 \\
    2 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 4 \\
    \cdot & 1 & \cdot & 2 & 3 \\
    \cdot & 5 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
    5 & 2 & 4 & 1 & \cdot
\end{array}
Actually, it is false even when $n=4$:
\begin{array}{cccc}
   2 & 1 & 4 & \cdot \\
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
   \cdot & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
   4 & \cdot & 1 & 3
\end{array}

The arrays we get at the end are called maximal partial Latin squares. A Latin square is a well-known object: an $n \times n$ grid filled with the numbers $1$ through $n$ so that no number repeats in any row or column. A partial Latin square is a grid with the same condition in which some cells may be left empty; it is maximal if we cannot fill any of the empty cells.
Horak and Rosa studied these in the paper book chapter Maximal partial Latin squares, and there is something to the idea that the number of unfilled cells is less likely to be odd. Horak and Rosa prove some limits on the size (number of filled squares) of an $n\times n$ maximal partial Latin square:

It cannot be less than $\frac{n^2}{2}$;
If the size is between $\frac{n^2}{2}$ and $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$, it must be even when $n$ is even and odd when $n$ is odd (leaving an odd number of unfilled cells);
It cannot be $n^2-1$.

This eliminates many cases with with an odd number of unfilled cells, especially when $n$ is small.
However, Horak and Rosa also show that maximal partial latin squares exist of all sizes larger than $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$ and smaller than $n^2-1$; in particular, for all $n\ge 4$, this includes cases with an odd number of unfilled cells. In the range between $\frac{n^2}{2}$ and $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$, there are still some cases where the existence of a maximal partial Latin square of that size is unknown.
